# what is the CoreGraphics and zone_calloc?

Tags: ios, animation, memory-management, core-graphics, instruments

This pic [not included here because as new user, I am not allowed to post images] is a Screenshot of Instruments(Allocations). It say the Responsible Library is CoreGraphics and the Responsible Caller is zone_calloc.

1. Please explain what is the CoreGraphics and zone_calloc?
2. Why they malloc so much(588kb)?
3. what should I do if I want to reduce the memory alloc?
4. How much memory alloc before the app will killed by OS?I heard is 20MB,but I'm not sure.

PS: I use a lot of animation in my app, I guess the 7*588kb memory alloc is related of my menu,because it is have 7 menu items in my app.